# Twisting rectangle with text surface

Tags: animation, uv

I'm trying to do something similar to this is Blender:

[image]

Animation here: https://www.instagram.com/p/BqQKtNmHsCw/

I can get the shape and animation to look quite similar based on the linked answer, but how do I actually add the text uv texture to my object?

Comment: Thanks. Just added an image of the desired effect.

Comment: Hi. If the linked question doesn't help, then please explain *why* it doesn't help and how your question differs.

Comment: @AllanKristiansen your second question (about texturing and UV), ask it on a new post using the blue  "Ask Question" box at the top right of the page. You might want to add a link to this page as part of the text of the new question.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Comment: Again, ask further questions in new posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave it a try:

[image]

1. Start with a Bezier Circle *(Add > Curve > Circle)*
2. Add a cube and change the x-dimension to 2 * pi. You can calculate directly in the input field and you can use constants like pi. It should be 6.28 m and so it fits the circumference.
3. In Edit Mode gave the cube some additional loop cuts with *CTRL+R*. Scale the cube to your liking, but keep the x-dimension. In scale-mode press *Shift-x* to lock scaling on that axis. Delete the end faces. It should look like this: [image]
   **Edit: Make even more subdivisions ;)**
4. Add a Simple-Deform-Modifier. Set it's mode to *Twist*, the Axis to *X* and the Angle to *360°*
5. Add a Curve-Modifier. Due to our calculation it fits perfectly.[image]
6. To animate the twisting you can animate the cubes x-rotation[image]
7. For Texturing unwrap your cube and place your stripes on the text created in an image editor of your choice.
   You can animate the texture later. Therefore you can rotate every second stripe around 180° to let them move in opposite directions.[image]
8. To animate the texture set up your material and animate the x-location.[image]

Hope that helps! ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I can't seem to twist around the x axis? I've tried using an empty and rotating it, but it doesn't twist the object on the right axis..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try all axis? You have to rotate the cube around the longest axis. Maybe there is something rotated in the local axis? Try ro apply the cubes scale and rotation by pressing CTRL+A

Comment: I followed the linked answer above and got the shape and animation to work now, but now I just need to figure out how to do the text texture and animating it. Thanks for your help!